# Where is the dist directory in VS when running Angular template?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core

We're successfully running a new Angular application created and hosted under VS2017 in the very default template (Core + Angular). We promise that we made no changes to it. Seriously.

While it's running, we expected that a *dist* directory would be present in *wwwroot* (or at the very least somewhere within the solution structure). It is not.

We've googled the issue trusting there was a gazillion programmers before us asking the very same thing. Turns out... not that many. And the blogs we've found were more about how to make stuff work and be served.

Where does the *dist* with the bundled files reside?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Not questioning your statement at all. Still, it would be nice to have a reference to show to others. Is there any way to enforce to run it from the drive instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you publish from VS the dist folder generated in publish package.

Comment: Suer. I want to see the files while running VS, before I publish. I was expecting them to be there.

Comment: The new angular-cli version with webpack will generate dist folder only after ng build.

ng serve works only in-memory now. so you have to manually run ng build command

Comment: If your main concern about to see dist folder which can be only done by ng build and if you are not agree, can you please provide more details what you want exactly?

Comment: Might be my experience with C# - when you debug, you get a *bin* directory so you can see that "something" goes on. So it's possible that my question lacked relevance and was purely academicly driven. (BTW, I didn't downvote. In fact I upped you right back up.) If you summarize your comments in the body of the answer, I'll gladly accept it as the correct one.