# Where is the dist folder generated by Visual Studio when running an Angular Web Application?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Running Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition, though this applies to VS2017 and other versions of 2017/2019 as well.

When building/running an ASP.NET Core Web Application with an Angular web project, the `dist` folder is nowhere to be found. I'm well-aware that running `ng build` manually will generate it within the `ClientApp` directory. (I'm presenting fighting the issue if my application not auto-reloading when I change HTML/TypeScript/etc., and know that that's a symptom, so it's never there/I delete it immediately.)

Where does Visual Studio generate the required `dist` folder and files in order to render the Angular SPA I'm seeing in my browser right now? I can't seem to find it on disk anywhere. Not within the solution, nor in the bin, nor in the hidden `.vs` folder.

If you do know, do you also know of any official documentation that outlines whatever behavior it's using? At this point my only guess is that it's holding the entire application in memory, but I'm just not sure and would like clarity here.

Comment: I run `ng-bulid` in the `ClientApp` and the `dist` folder just show there...Or could you try to publish project from VS,refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571481/where-is-the-dist-directory-in-vs-when-running-angular-template

Comment: I'm not looking for where I can force `dist` to appear. I know I can build via `ng-build` or publish in order to get the files.

This question pertains to where Visual Studio is generating `dist` when running it locally. It doesn't seem to be anywhere on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Angular "dist" Folder Is Not Created When Developing

This has been confusing to me, too, until I read this at Angular's website:

> During development, you typically use the ng serve command to build,
> watch, and serve the application from local memory, using
> webpack-dev-server

**That means no `"dist"` ("distribution") folder is built for your Angular files as the build runs "in-memory".**

### More Details Below...

In ASP.NET Core, when you create web applications, those projects are usually tested by working on source code that you then build and view in a browser using one of several available servers. This allows you to test both compiled and non-compiled code files, and changes quickly. This allows you to test production-ready code.

In the Angular world it does not work that way. You are not testing from a static build but using the `Angular CLI` command set inside a command prompt on your PC to test in-memory versions of your code. This is completely alien to the Microsoft way.

The recommended command is `ng serve` using the command prompt. This allows you to run your Angular Application and see your website, even in ASP.NET. When it does so, it builds and runs your Angular application **in memory**. So the compiled "dist" folder is not created because the *built* code is stored in-memory when testing.

This is still counter-intuitive to me as most web developers in multiple modern frameworks today are used to working with physical files they either compile and run or view in the browser. This is not the case in the open source Angular world!

I blame JavaScript for this problem, since its the background language behind Angular and never was a compiled language. It is typically only JIT compiled on-demand by browser JavaScript engines right before code is run. Because modern JavaScript API's like Angular are actually written in **TypeScript**, a very odd *transpile* model is used to create these types of JavaScript API applications, which is not typical. These API's are often not transpiled to raw JavaScript until *Publish* and/or *Production* code is created, though browser JS engines can work with TypeScript files now.

Because *JavaScript* is not a true compiled or typed language (like C, C++, C#, Java, etc), this model adds extra steps and confusion to developers, and explains why **Angular has a steep learning curve**. This creates confusion in ASP.NET using Angular, as now you are forced to work with non-compiled code you cannot truly test or even build on-the-fly, like *ASP.NET C#*. You are also dependent on a 3rd party dependency (Node) for a special *dev server* to do so.

To manage all this, you are encouraged to use the following CLI command to test your Angular application, even in ASP.NET: `ng serve`. When testing with `ng serve`, in summary, it actually runs several stages of your Angular typescript code, including a build or TypeScript-to-JavaScript in-memory Angular compile/transpile, test configurations, an optional "watch" build, a development server, proxy's to resources, and more. This command also starts up a server called an "Angular Development Server" from the command prompt, which also runs in memory.

Angular on their web site recommends you use this model. So Microsoft in Visual Studio in ASP.NET Core has adopted it, as well. They don't tell you that, as most would assume Angular simply builds its final codebase for you to link to as physical files. But this is not the case. So the `dist` folder is not ever created, until you go to Publish.

**To get around this problem, there are several solutions.** I will not go into how to set up Angular as a project in Visual Studio, how to use the proxy system, or how link to your raw build files in development. That is another topic. But I have posted an ASP.NET Core C# solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76102691/5555938

But if you simply want to build your Google Angular application in *Microsoft ASP.NET Core 7* (MVC or WebAPI), just open up any command prompt on your PC and type the following. This assume you have installed the Angular CLI and Node.js. This creates the `"dist"` or *distribution folder* with your final Angular compiled code in JavaScript:

```
cd c:\your path to your angular project root folder
ng build
```

Your Angular application *project root folder* in ASP.NET Core is typically called `"ClientApp"` and inside your ASP.NET MVC folder. Your Angular application `"dist"` folder will be created using the code above, and is typically stored here: `"ClientApp/dist"`

Because compiling into the `"dist"` folder moves you from the *development phase* in the Angular world and into the *production phase*, its nearly impossible to make Angular development changes working from the compiled copy and is not typically recommended since its not the *TypeScript* source code. However, Angular on their website under Deployment, does offer some techniques to test changes in Angular that build and reconstitute the in-memory copy when running `ng serve`. `ng build --watch` is one example.

But that is another topic.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Angular.json and look for `outPath`:

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      "outputPath": "dist/",
```

Comment: Just says `dist`. Not too helpful, unfortunately.